# grep - print line before, don't print match

Tags: awk, grep

How to easily print line above the match and skip the match itself? `grep` `-A`, `-B` and `-o` opt do not solve it. Maybe some `awk` magic?

for example:

```
$ cat foo.txt
bar
foo
baz
foo

$ cat foo.txt | grep foo-SOMETHING
bar
baz
```

**Edit**

- in case when line 2 and 3 has "foo", then line 1 and 2 should be printed (although I am not very strict here)

Additional feature: consider the example:

```
bar
foo
baz
foo
foo
```

This should ideally return

```
bar
baz
foo
```

Comment: What's wrong with `-B`?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth it prints the preceding line AND the matching line.

Comment: what about two continuous lines both match `foo` ? print the first line? or ignore both?

Comment: @Barmar: I am aware of that, but that can be worked around against.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
awk '!/foo/ { line = $0 }
     /foo/ { print line }' foo.txt
```

The first clause saves each non-foo line in a variable. The second clause prints the most recent saved line when the line matches `foo`.

This also works (and handles the case where you have two `foo` lines in a row):

```
awk '/foo/ {print line}
     {line = $0}' foo.txt
```

With `grep` you can do:

```
grep -B 1 foo foo.txt | grep -vE 'foo|^--$'
```

The second command filters out the `foo` lines and the dividers that are printed between the matching blocks.

Comment: If a line containing `foo` should be printed when it is followed by a line matching `foo`, refactor to `awk '/foo/{print line}{line=$0}' foo.txt`

Comment: Shouldn't `awk '/foo/{ print line } { line = $0 }' foo.txt` be sufficient?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: Please post it as an answer, it behaves better in when dealing with repeated matching pattern (see edited question)

Comment: @JakubM. It's in my answer, also Vijay's answer.

Comment: @Barmar: I thought Adrian was first before you, sorry if I am wrong

Comment: @JakubM. He was. I updated my answer in response to his suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Just set `p` to the pattern you want:

```
$ awk '$0~p{print a}{a=$0}' p="foo" file
bar
baz
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/foo/{print a}{a=$0}' your_file
```